# Javascript: Append to HTMLcollection of nodes

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does this not work?

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("abc");
nodes += document.getElementsByClassName("xyz");
```

Second line corrupts nodes variable. Classes exist in the HTML page.
Any way to have this working?

Comment: have you read about how javascript arrays work? Keyword: array.push / array.concat

Comment: use concat or just use array.push : MDS documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: @Jankapunkt `HTMLcollection` is not an array.

Comment: Then the headline should be changed to `Javascript: Append HTMLCollection`

Comment: Yes, it should be changed, and the tag as well, since the problem here is not related to arrays. OP doesn't know this, which is quite normal in a S.O. question. People trying to answer, however, should know that `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: You are correct. However, a collection is a sort of array. I'm sorry I didn't use the correct vocabulary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this too :

```
var abc_nodes = Array.prototype.slice
                     .apply(document.getElementsByClassName("abc")),
    xyz_nodes = Array.prototype.slice
                     .apply(document.getElementsByClassName("xyz"));

var all_nodes = abc_nodes.concat(xyz_nodes);
```

Comment: This solution was the only one working in IE11. Yes, I didn't mention that in my original post but hopefully can the other answers help people that don't use IE.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to append to `HTMLCollection`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

You can however, convert it to array and join them.

```js
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("abc");
var nodes2 = document.getElementsByClassName("xyz");


var nodeList = []
  .concat(Array.from(nodes))
  .concat(Array.from(nodes2));

console.log(nodeList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc">1</div>
<div class="abc">2</div>
<div class="abc">3</div>

<div class="xyz">4</div>
<div class="xyz">5</div>
```

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Syntax error",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 23,
  "colno": 3
}

Comment: Is your browser support javascript es6 features? Tested with Chrome and Firefox. All good. https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=500526645512

Comment: See comment to Dhananjaya Kuppu above

Comment: added polyfill. It should run in IE11.

Comment: Run results in: 1

2

3

4

5
 


[
  <div class="abc">1</div>,
  <div class="abc">2</div>,
  <div class="abc">3</div>,
  <div class="xyz">4</div>,
  <div class="xyz">5</div>
]

Comment: That's right. because I console.log the output to screen.

Comment: I'm quite content with Dhananjaya Kuppu's answer. No additional code needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way you can get the array in JavaScript. You can read more about it here [JavaScript Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

To Answer your question, the possible solution can be

```
var nodes = [element1];
nodes.push(element2);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It could be better explained if you use OP's code and loop the array and push element one by one. just a suggestion.

Comment: That could have been the direct answer. As per the OPs question, its seems that he should understand the basics of the JavaScript array. I showed him direction and he will find the solution, I suppose

Comment: IE cannot comprehend .push

Answer (score -1):

`getElementsByClassName`returns an HTMLCollection, which is an [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), so you can easily parse it to an Array using

```
var nodes = [document.getElementsByClassName("abc")];
nodes = nodes.concat([document.getElementsByClassName("xyz")];
```

However, it's internal structure is the same as an Object and you can therefore also use `Object.values`.

```
var nodes = Object.values(document.getElementsByClassName("abc"));
nodes = nodes.concat(document.getElementsByClassName("xyz"));
```

You can wrap this inside a function, that takes an arbitrary length of class names and returns an array from it:

```js
function nodesToArray(...args) {
  let final = [];
  for (let arg of args) {
    final = final.concat(Object.values(document.getElementsByClassName(arg)));  
  }
  return final;
}

console.log(nodesToArray('abc', 'xyz'));
```

```html
<div class="abc">bla</div>
<div class="abc">bla</div>
<div class="xyz">bla</div>
<div class="xyz">bla</div>
```

which can be called via `nodesToArray('abc', 'xyz')`.

Now all this can be wrapped up in a one-liner:

```js
const nodesToArray = (...args) => args.map(arg => Object.values(document.getElementsByClassName(arg))).reduce((node1, node2) => node1.concat(node2));

console.log(nodesToArray('abc', 'xyz'));
```

```html
<div class="abc">bla</div>
<div class="abc">bla</div>
<div class="xyz">bla</div>
<div class="xyz">bla</div>
```

So you can get an array of the HTML nodes by classnames

Comment: I get "Error message..." when I try to run your code snippets.
I did not downvote you.

Comment: Which browser do you use? For me the snippets run fine.

Comment: See comment to Dhananjaya Kuppu above